# Can we increase Thread count in JMeter during load test ? not scheduled increment..!

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Can we increase Thread count in JMeter during load test ? 
i am using Jmeter3.2 version , how can i configure this or increase thread count during load test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot manipulate the number of threads (virtual users) however you can control the number of requests per minute (aka throughput) in the real time, it should be  a feasible alternative.

1. Add [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) to your Thread Group
2. Define desired initial throughput as a JMeter Property using [__P() function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#beanshell_server) like `${__P(throughput,)}`:

   [image: JMeter Constant Throughput Timer]
3. That's it, now you can control how often your requests are executed by modifying `throughput` property for example using [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty). Moreover, you can even do this outside of JMeter via for example [Beanshell Server](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#beanshell_server)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot increase number of threads (as Vins said), but you can start *maximum* threads you need, and get most threads to idle until test tells them to do something.

For example: lets say you want to start with 5 threads, and increase them to 10 when `myVar` becomes `true`:

```
Thread Group 
 Number of threads: 10

    While Controller 
     Condition: ${__javaScript(${__threadNum} > 5 && '${myVar}' != 'true')}

       Constant Timer <-- thread will idle here for a bit and check condition again

    Samplers <-- when not idling, script starts here
```

So threads above 5 will idle under While Controller, checking condition periodically (period is dictated by Constant Timer). When condition is no longer satisfied, they will exit While and continue with script execution.

Of course this just shows a method, you can tailor it to your needs (e.g. condition can be simple or complex, you can enable and disable threads dynamically by modifying variable multiple times, and so on).

Comment: Brilliant! One small query tho. myVar was initialized to false at some point in the script and later on based on some condition, it turns to true. So, during the second iteration, does myVar get reinitialized to false or does it retain the value from the previous iteration? I know that making it a static variable would help but does it hold good in JMeter across iterations as well?

Comment: The value does not change on its own, and once introduced, every thread will have that variable till the end of the run. So it depends on how you initialize it and whether you do want it changed on each iteration: you can reset it to false at the beginning of the script, so each iteration will start fresh, or you can do nothing, so it will stay 'true' once it was set to true. Or you can have another condition on when to set it to false. As I said earlier, this is just a method, you can adjust it further

Comment: Thanks for the response Kiril. Forgot about the existence of User Parameters (dumb me!)

Answer (score 1):

You can parameterize the thread count using variables / properties.  However once the test started, say with 5 threads, you can not change it to 10 threads while the test is running.

Answer (score 0):

You can use plugin [Ultimate thread group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/). You'll have to set it up before running the test. Unfortunately, you will not be able to add threads  manually during the test.